Java tries to load wrong library and throws Runtime Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/msv/reader/GrammarReaderController
I´m using my org project jar (called org-project-execution.jar) which includes a class called com.ctc.wstx.shaded.msv_core.reader.GrammarReaderController and import it in my Java program.
The code builds but when it calls the method "org.project.execution.Executor.execute(inputStream, inputLength)"` the following Error happens:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/msv/reader/GrammarReaderController
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
at org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.createNewInstance(XMLValidationSchemaFactory.java:306)
at org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLValidationSchemaFactory.java:140)
at org.codehaus.stax2.validation.XMLValidationSchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLValidationSchemaFactory.java:116)
at org.project.xsd.XsdSchema.loadSchemaResource(XsdSchema.java:41)
at org.project.xsd.XsdSchema.lambda$static$1(XsdSchema.java:26)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:178)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at org.project.xsd.XsdSchema.(XsdSchema.java:24)
at org.project.readers.PspXmlReader.lookupXsd(PspXmlReader.java:280)
at org.project.readers.PspXmlReader.(PspXmlReader.java:69)
at org.project.execution.Executor.execute(Executor.java:86)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:135)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3869)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3832)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2505)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2354)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2329)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2307)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1798)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1752)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.msv.reader.GrammarReaderController
at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.findClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:399)
at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:372)
at com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:55)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 66 more

For some reason java tries to load a com/sun/msv/reader/GrammarReaderController instead of  the com.ctc.wstx.shaded.msv_core.reader.GrammarReaderController included in the project jar. Then I tried including a msv-core-2022.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar that has com/sun/msv/reader/GrammarReaderController in it, build the project, but the code still throws the same Runtime error. How is the method .execute not finding the GrammarReaderController in the right import and tries to find in some other package?

An import statement in your class doesn’t make other classes use that class. It only affects name resolution in that one specific source file containing the import statement.

I understand. I also have to mention that the jar files are included in the lib folder of the project.
